# Twitter share button opens in full window

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQLdLg and I want to give the popup share window the size I want, be smaller and centered. Right now it opens in a full window.

I have tried with `onclick="window.open(this.href,width=400,height=250);return false;` but couldn't make it to work.

Comment: How is this PHP?

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner. do you know how to make this exact code work with a smaller new window? thank you!

Comment: That's okay. Glad you got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Demo:** https://codepen.io/kumarrishikesh12/pen/VWxgbY

---

> **Facebook**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com/" id="facebookurl" name="fb_url" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
```

> **Linkdin**

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.example.com/&title=myexample" id="linkedinurl" name="linkedin_url" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
```

> **twitter**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20my%20new%20webpage%21&via=example&url=http://www.example.com" id="twitternurl" name="twitter_url" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
```

```html
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VWxgbY" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="kumarrishikesh12" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Add share popup to links" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/kumarrishikesh12/pen/VWxgbY/">Add share popup to links</a> by Rishikesh kumar (<a href="https://codepen.io/kumarrishikesh12">@kumarrishikesh12</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: @rid ... your `twitter' share model here .. https://codepen.io/kumarrishikesh12/pen/eRrxLx

Comment: you are great, RïshïKêsh Kümar!